# How do I generate a paper wallet for Bitcoin Cash

Tags: paper-wallet, bitcoin-cash

I can't find any tools to generate Bitcoin cash paper wallet - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same tool as for Bitcoin

Comment: Can I use the same private key to store both BTC and BCC?

Comment: You can technically do it, but I do not recommend it

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a paper-wallet generator that utilizes CashAddr? (In order of my preference)

- [CashAddress.org](https://cashaddress.org/)
- [WalletGenerator.net/?currency=BitcoinCash](https://walletgenerator.net/?currency=BitcoinCash)
- [PaperWallet.cash](http://paperwallet.cash/) (Manually https)
- [BCCAddress.org](http://bccaddress.org/index.html) (Manually https)
- [tools.bitcoin.com/paper-wallet/](https://tools.bitcoin.com/paper-wallet/)
- [www.paperwalletgenerator.com/BitcoinCash/](https://www.paperwalletgenerator.com/BitcoinCash/)
- [bitcoincashpaperwallet.de](https://bitcoincashpaperwallet.de/) (German)